# Open Graph Facebbok SDK2.5

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm a bit confused about all the open graph mechanism for request and send objects. 
Currently I'm doing the following:

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
gameRequestContent.message = [SPBLabelUtils stringMessageForKey:@"FacebookAskLivesMessage"];
gameRequestContent.recipients = friends;
gameRequestContent.objectID = @"794790780644074";
gameRequestContent.actionType = FBSDKGameRequestActionTypeAskFor;

FBSDKGameRequestDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc] init];
dialog.frictionlessRequestsEnabled = TRUE;
dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
dialog.delegate = self;
NSError *error;
if([dialog canShow] && [dialog validateWithError:&error]){
    [dialog show];
}else if(error){
    [self showAlertForError:error];
}
else{
    [self showAlertWithMessage:[SPBErrors messageForCode:@"FBE:CantShowDialog"] title:[SPBLabelUtils stringMessageForKey:@"FacebookTitle"]];
}
```

and getting the following error in my:

`- (void)gameRequestDialog:(FBSDKGameRequestDialog *)gameRequestDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)" UserInfo=0x17887f7c0
>   {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Sorry, this feature
>   isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this
>   request. Please try again later.}

I'm not sure I completely understand the `objectID` idea - do I need to create an object every time I need to ask for it?
And if I do, do I need to use the 'create code' and link it to a page to a page that contains all the metadata?
Why would I create a new object every time? I don't even need to read it, just to inform the other players that they have an object request pending.

The API is not 100% clear tbh.
If someone can explain\give a tutorial link\post sample code it'll be lovely. 
Thanks

Comment: If FB is saying that this feature isn't available right now, then I guess you find another way around.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the ID for your Object? The one you are using is a sample object. You will need to create (at least) one real Open Graph object, which you can use in your code to refer to.

Comment: I've solved it some time ago but that was the reason. Their objects creation platform is a bit sloppy...

Comment: Happy that you fixed it! For in the future, can you edit your question or add an answer, so that others with the same issue can find the solution?

Comment: Yeah sure. I usually do. Cheers

Comment: By the way: What about the Victory object? should I used the sample one? as I'm not allowed to create victory objects. (as far as I concerned)

Answer (score 1):

I have stucked on this for several hours. Hope someone can find solution on this question in my answer.

In your project settings go to "Open Graph" section on facebook. Create some Object Type. Then there is a button on the top "Tools & support".

After click you will see several links, the one you need is "Object browser".

Object browser is required section. There is on combobox with "Type:" text, It contains our object types that we have created earlier. An there is a button "New object" for selected type.

When you will create New object than It gets his Id.
And that is your Object Id you are looking for.

May be there is a better way to find section "Object Browser".

And one more important thing:

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *Content = [[ FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc ] init];
            Content.title = @"Title test";
            Content.message = @"Test message";
            Content.data = @"Test data";
            Content.objectID = @"1012001268809871";
            Content.actionType = FBSDKGameRequestActionTypeAskFor;
            Content.filters = FBSDKGameRequestFilterAppUsers;
            fbRequestDialog.content = Content;
            fbRequestDialog.delegate = self;
            BOOL Result = [ fbRequestDialog show ];
```

This code works fine for me. So as you can see "objectID" field is string but it represents numeric string. Now you know how does it look like.